# apksigner --v4-no-merkle-tree option does not exist

Tags: apksigner

The [Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner#options-sign-general) explained that there is an option `--v4-no-merkle-tree` but the option does not exist. I'm doing this way to sign via CMD

```
java -jar ApkSigner.jar sign --ks "test.jks" --ks-pass pass:****** --v4-signing-enabled true --v4-no-merkle-tree --out signed.apk target.apk
```

I'm using latest build-tools 31.0.0-rc1. Previous versions does not have the option too

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a documentation error. The flag does not exist nor has ever existed.

Edit: Now removed from documentation.